# Allowing functions to go through in a world with no cheats

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I'm currently having a problem with a datapack I'm making, in a part of it, there's a tellraw that will summon an item at the player's position, and take points from a scoreboard, basically a shop.

However, this can't be done if cheats are not enabled on the world, it says the command is either incomplete or non existent.

Is there anyway to allow access to this function in a world where there is no cheats?

This is what's inside the function:

```
execute at @s[scores={money=150..}] run summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"diamond",Damage:0,Count:1}}
scoreboard players remove @s[scores={money=150..}] money 150
execute at @s run playsound minecraft:block.chain.break master @a ~ ~ ~ 2 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I let player click text to use a command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316754/how-can-i-let-player-click-text-to-use-a-command)